# How do I compose a list from an Association such that the final product matches a fixed percentage of each of four subsets?

Tags: associations, subset

My question is in two parts. The first is about picking discrete elements inside a list of Associations to match a fixed percentage of a final sub-list; the second is about overcoming the rounding problem the first part creates.

I have data in a List of Associations, a portion of which looks like this

```
{<|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1101, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0946|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1102,  "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0901|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1103, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.00876|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1104, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0242|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1105, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0783|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1106, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0433|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1107, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0253|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1108, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.1144|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1109, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.1036|>, <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 111, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.1216|>, <<145845>>}
```

The first Key = Sector has four possibilities, A, B, C and D

I need to compose a sub-list **OF UNIQUE VALUES** which has a fixed (but uneven) percentage of each sector. Here is an example where the proportions correspond to "A","B","C" and "D"

```
{0.13, 0.19, 0.28, 0.4}
```

Note the decimals must add to unity.

So, to be completely tedious, a sub-list of, say, 1033 elements would have

```
Round[1033 {0.13, 0.19, 0.28, 0.4}]
```

to get this

```
(*{134, 196, 289, 413}*)
```

...which adds to 1032. What I need should be the total sought less the first three proportions, producing the fourth. I am sure there is a better way than this, but this works

```
Join[Round[1033 #], {1033 - Plus @@ Round[1033 #]}] &[{0.13, 0.19, 
  0.28}]
```

@MarcoB suggested this

```
grupBySec = GroupBy[netLoA, #"Sector" &];
RandomChoice[{0.13, 0.19, 0.28, 0.4} -> grupBySec]
```

but it only randomizes the sector. It looks like the Documentation for weights but those examples do not use Associations

Comment: Group your list of associations by the value corresponding to the sector key, then sample from the list of lists with RandomChoice, using `{0.13, 0.19, 0.28, 0.4}` as weights?

Comment: @MarcoB - my FAULT!!! The sample is without replacement. I edited the above (BOLD). Since you got 1033 picks out of 1000 there are duplicates. Am presently combing through your code to find a solution

Comment: That's actually an easy fix: use `RandomSample` instead of `RandomChoice`. I've updated my answer to reflect that and added a check for duplicates.

Comment: Great!! I really appreciate it. I know SE frowns on superfluous commentary but it is hard to restrain myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first generate some fake data `fakeList` that has the same structure as your list:

```
n = 10000;
fakeList = MapThread[
   <|"Sector" -> #1, "ID" -> #2, "Year" -> #3, "AnnReturn" -> #4|> &,
   {
     RandomChoice[{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, n],
     Range[1101, 1101 + n - 1],
     RandomInteger[{1990, 2000}, n],
     RandomReal[{0, 0.2}, n]
   }
];
```

Let's now assign your weights to a variable for readability:

```
weights = {0.13, 0.19, 0.28, 0.4};
```

---

With those in hand, let's reorganize the list, grouping it by `"Sector"`. We also sort it to make sure that the groups are listed in alphabetical order of sector, so the relative weights are correctly assigned to each sector later on:

```
organizedList = SortBy[#Sector &@*First]@GatherBy[fakeList, #Sector &]
```

Let's now generate the number of samples to pick for each group, based on the number of desired samples overall. I use your example of 1033 samples:

```
With[{samples = 1033},
 counts = {##, samples - Total[{##}]} & @@ Round[samples weights[[;; 3]]]
]

(* Out: {134, 196, 289, 414} *)
```

Now let's pick a random selection *without replacement* of samples according to the output above from each grouped list. We do that using [`RandomSample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html), which never samples any element more than once from its input.

```
picks =
  MapThread[
    RandomSample[#1, #2] &,
    {organizedList, counts}
  ] // Flatten

(* Out: 
{<|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1952, "Year" -> 1994, "AnnReturn" -> 0.163849|>, 
 <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1822, "Year" -> 1998, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0230599|>, 
 <|"Sector" -> "A", "ID" -> 1670, "Year" -> 1992, "AnnReturn" -> 0.0859481|>, 
 
 <<1027>>,

 <|"Sector" -> "D", "ID" -> 1651, "Year" -> 1999, "AnnReturn" -> 0.102282|>, 
 <|"Sector" -> "D", "ID" -> 2074, "Year" -> 1996, "AnnReturn" -> 0.192641|>, 
 <|"Sector" -> "D", "ID" -> 1539, "Year" -> 1990, "AnnReturn" -> 0.00170126|>}
*)
```

Finally, let's check that we did indeed obtain the right number of samples from each "Sector" in the output:

```
CountsBy[#Sector &][picks]

(* Out: <|"A" -> 134, "B" -> 196, "C" -> 289, "D" -> 414|> *)
```

... and that there are no duplicates in the output:

```
DeleteDuplicates[picks] == picks
(* True *)
```